# Promise.all doesn't work properly

Tags: typescript, promise

I have an `update` method taking some data and returning a Promise.
I want to run this method in parallel on a set of data with `Promise.all`.
But debugging it, I see it doesn't behave as expected.

Update method (Typescript) uses promisified Azure TableService, which returns promise as well:

```
public update(data: string): Promise<void> {
    // prepare data...
    return this._tableService.replaceEntity(TABLE_NAME, entity);
}
```

1. Update method not called on set of data, promise resolved immediately.

   ```
   var updatePromises = [];
   data.forEach(item => {          
      updatePromises.push(() => this.update(item));
   }
   return Promise.all(updatePromises);
   ```
2. Update method is called immediately after pushing (not in Promise.all), promise resolved immediately.

   ```
   var updatePromises = [];
   data.forEach(item => {          
      updatePromises.push(this.update(item));
   }
   return Promise.all(updatePromises);
   ```

Comment: If your `update` function is synchronous (doesn't have any `await`s or delayed callbacks resolving the promise) then the promise will resolve as soon as you call the function.

Comment: nope it is async and uses promises

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: The first snippet is wrong, `Promise.all` doesn't take an array of functions. The second one should work, I don't get how you expect the method be "called in `Promise.all`".

Comment: Btw,use `map` instead of `forEach`

Comment: I mean the functions sould be called after the line `Promise.all` ..., not at the moment of pushing. Posted part of the code.

Comment: can you show the code for `replaceEntity` method in `TableService` class?

Comment: `update` is declared as returning `Promise<void>`, but I don't see a `return` statement.  Did you mean to return a promise from `this._tableService.replaceEntity(TABLE_NAME, entity)`?  (TypeScript should have given an error about this.)

Comment: yeah there is a return

Comment: the usual function: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/d7b7e16f7d7e08852f4fa1fb477acbdf0cc281d7/lib/services/table/tableservice.js#L1046 is wrapped via `promisify`. Can this be why promise.all doesn't work?

Comment: Promises are eager not lazy, you can't make them start all at the same time, you can only wait for all of them with Promise.all

Comment: @annaoomph "*I mean the functions sould be called after the line Promise.all ..., not at the moment of pushing*" - but why do you care? You *have* to call the functions to get the promises before you can pass the promises to `Promise.all`.

Comment: @annaoomph Can you show how exactly you are using `promisify` and calling the wrapped function?

Answer (score 0):

Nolan Lawson, in his excellent ["We have a problem with promises"](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html), addresses the problem with both of your code samples directly:

> The TLDR of all this is that `forEach()`/`for`/`while` are not the constructs you're looking for. You want [to combine `.map()` with] `Promise.all()`.

Using his example (and Bergi's comment above) as a model, you could `resolve` all of this (hee hee) in your code by

3. Creating your array of promises *inside* of `Promise.all()`:

   ```
   return Promise.all(data.map(item => this.update(item)))
   ```